# Как сделать пагинацию в модуле mod_k2_users joomla3

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3, gtk2

В сборке К2 присутствует стандартный модуль для вывода списка авторов. К сожалению вывести список авторов штатными средствами можно только посредством модуля (вывод списка авторов через пункт меню функционалом не предусмотрен). 
Данное решение хорошо при небольшом количестве авторов. Если количество авторов 200-300, 500 и более то выводить такое количество записей на одной странице будет не рационально.

Возможно кто-то знает как сделать пагинацию в модуле mod_k2_users. 
Также принимаются варианты альтернативного вывода авторов K2 с постраничной разбивкой или отложенной загрузкой при пролистывании страницы.

K2 v2.8.0
Joomla! 3.8.5

Большое спасибо!